# Trying to get Month and year range using Moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to calculate Month name and year using moment for a range.
for example if the start year and month is 2016-02, and end year is 2017-11,

I want Moment to create date in 
Feb-16 , Mar-16 ..Jan-17, Nov-17

Can you provide some idea? This is what I ma trying to do:

```
     const startYear = 2016;
    const startMonth = 2;
    const endYear = 2017;
    const endMonth = 12;
    var ind = startMonth;
    var i=0;

    while(i < 24){

      if(ind == 13){
        ind = 1; 
        startYear++;
      }
      header = moment(startYear + '-'+ ind, 'YYYY-M').format('MMM-YY');
      i++;
      ind++;
      return header ;
    }
```

The output should be like :
Feb-16 Mar-16 Apr-16 May-16......Jan-17....Nov-17

Comment: Please show us some code. What have you tried so far

Comment: could you please explain  what actually you want to achieve??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when `momentjs` a library, try to use the convenience methods that they have for date manipulation instead of just using it for parsing

```
var startDate = moment('2012-1');
var endDate = moment('2013-1');
var out = [startDate];

while (startDate.isBefore(endDate)) {
  startDate = startDate.add(1, 'month');
  out.push(startDate);
}
```